# Call REST API from another project

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, microservices

I have two projects one for user and another for department.

Now I want to call a REST API from another REST API. How can I call?

I am facing problem because user related classes are not available for department and vice versa.

This is my UserController class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired   
    UserService userService;
    @GetMapping(value="/get", headers="Accept=application/json")
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        List<User> tasks=userService.getUser();
        return tasks;
    }
```

And this is my DepartmentController class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dept")
@Configurable
public class DeptController {
@Autowired
    DeptServiceImpl deptService;
@GetMapping(value="/get", headers="Accept=application/json")
        public List<User> getDept() {
            List<Department> tasks=deptService.getDept();
            return tasks;
        }
```

Please tell me how to call getUser() method in getDept(), and how to make classes available for each other.

Comment: If you're building microservices, you don't call the methods in Java, you call them using an HTTP request like any other client would. Sharing classes would also introduce coupling that's probably not desirable.

Comment: Tell you what by example? How to make an HTTP request from a Spring app? That seems like it would be relatively easy to research via a search engine.

Comment: basically, If User app runs on localhost 8080 then you must call http://localhost:8080/user from your Dept app.

Comment: [`RestTemplate`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest) class the one you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to expose your microservice resources as rest APIs so you can call them from outside, and then you can use RestTemplate from spring to retrieve your information

**EDIT**

here is a good [example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-restful/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/) you can rely on to achieve what you want